# Make a htaccess line that rewrite this

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a adress that I really would like to both shorten and make look much nicer :-)

`http://www.mysubdomain.mydomain.com/test/make/n.php?o=My%20test&template=Lovely`

The parameters that are important are: o=  and template=

How can I make a htaccess that allows me to go to the main domain and use this adress
`http://www.mydomain.com/Lovely/My%20test`
and it will show the content of the above link/ page?

I have read a lot about htacces, but haven't figured this out. Whatever I test it just doesn't work. So I hope I can get help from one or many htaccess experts ;-)

To recap: My intention is to make a short URL like this: mydomain.com/templatename/special%20words
that will show the content of the first link in this post.

Thank you :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that should work for you:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^[^/]*/[^/]*/?$ n.php?o=$1&template=$2 [L,QSA]
```